Where to learn about new wireless adapter compatibility
I recently built a new work computer using a newly released motherboard, the Asus X870-I. The motherboard has Wi-Fi antennas similar to the family desktop computer.
Unfortunately, I wasn't smart enough to check for compatibility of the built-in wireless adapter with Ubuntu before buying the and installing the motherboard. (I only use Ubuntu for work.) It seems the motherboard and its wireless adapter are too new to plug-and-play for the latest Ubuntu LTS. In the meantime, I've purchased a USB wireless adapter that should be compatible with Linux.
I'm not expecting anyone to help me troubleshoot, I understand the drivers for this wireless adapter likely do not exist for Linux yet. I would just like to know:
What sources should I follow to learn about driver progress for the wireless adapter integrated into the Asus X870-I motherboard?

Linux doesn't target motherboards; but chipsets, or the chips that OEMs put on motherboards; so you're looking at the wrong thing, ie. you need to look at what chipset exists on your motherboard that provides the wifi.   You are right as whilst I do note 6.11 kernel packaged as hwe-24.04; it's not yet available for noble -- but you can download a oracular ISO to confirm that will help you via a live test anyway.

This question is similar to: My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. We need to know the what information is needed in order to search GitHub for projects that are specific to your Asus X870-I motherboard's wireless adapter.

When you know the wireless chipset, you can follow kernel development to see when that chipset get added, then Ubuntu development to see when that kernel gets pushed to the next release of Ubuntu. Or you can just try the built-in wifi after a release-upgrade and see if it starts working.

Thanks all. I think the chipset is known as MT7927 since it shows up as "Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 7927" from lspci. Searching for this chipset in forums lead me to https://github.com/morrownr/USB-WiFi/issues/431 which seems like a good issue to follow for updates. The owner of the repo mentioned there'd be an announcement when driver and firmware was posted for it https://github.com/morrownr/USB-WiFi/issues/537#issuecomment-2484426265 As for following kernel development, I'm not sure how to do that. I think it's not as intuitive as GitHub. I'm trying out Oracular 24.10 now.

I tried a live stick for 24.10 and it has the same results for the wireless adapter.

I still unsure of how to follow kernel development. Seems like following the https://github.com/morrownr/USB-WiFi GitHub repository is a good way to stay informed about the latest wireless chipsets and drivers supported on Linux.
For my motherboard, I found the chipset using lspci.
Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 7927

